# New Ubutu 20.04.4LTS shows only lo for networks

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, internet, ethernet

## edit added:
linux-firmware:
Installed: 1.187.27
Candidate: 1.187.27
Version table:
*** 1.187.27 100
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

I've got a Dell XPS 13 9315 with Ubuntu 20.04.4 freshly installed by Dell. It all works except I have no internet connection. Bluetooth works; `ping localhost` worked.

When I boot from a live Fedora 39 USB, everything runs fine.

`lspci` listed all pci devices. It found:

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f0 (rev 01)
```

`nmcli` shows only

```
lo: unmanaged
```

`iwconfig` gives:

```
lo   no wireless extensions
```

`lspci -k` to check the drivers in use:

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4090
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I tried to connect my iPhone via USB: "Activation of network connection failed." (I tried it twice.)

Amazon is sending me a ethernet->USB C adaptor. But I don't see any sign of an eth0 connector. (When booted into Fedora live, I can't find any eth0 either.)

It seems I need to update the Ubuntu installation and maybe get other drivers. But I can't without an internet connection.

Here's the output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` from Ubuntu:

```
[   15.332615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   15.341747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   15.341766] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.25
[   15.342079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   15.365141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[   16.392202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x80fb, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   16.392250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80480c70
[   16.392304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   16.392307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   16.640240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
[   16.640244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   16.640248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   16.640250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   16.640252] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   16.640254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   16.640256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   16.640258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   16.640260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   16.640261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   16.640263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   16.640265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   16.640267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   16.640269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   16.640270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   16.640272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   16.640273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   16.640274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   16.640276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   16.640277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   16.640278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   16.640280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   16.640281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   16.640282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   16.640283] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   16.640284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   16.640286] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   16.640287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   16.640289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   16.640291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   16.640293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   16.640295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   16.640296] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   16.640298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   16.640300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   16.640360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   16.640361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   16.640365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   16.640367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   16.640369] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045DE0C | umac branchlink2
[   16.640372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   16.640373] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   16.640375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[   16.640377] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | umac data2
[   16.640379] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | umac data3
[   16.640381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000040 | umac major
[   16.640383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x97BBEE0A | umac minor
[   16.640385] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00013F7D | frame pointer
[   16.640387] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F38 | stack pointer
[   16.640389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   16.640391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   16.640434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   16.640435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   16.640484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000080FB | IML/ROM data1
[   16.640536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   16.640543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   16.640596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   16.640646] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   16.640687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   16.640691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   16.640740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   16.640744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x10F80277 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   16.640788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   16.640795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   16.640844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   16.640896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   16.640948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00016C5B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   16.640991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   16.640999] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   16.641003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   17.794528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   17.807085] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[   17.807300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[   18.824410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x71e9, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   18.824460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80480c70
[   18.824512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   18.824518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   19.072935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
[   19.072942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   19.072946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   19.072948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   19.072950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   19.072952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   19.072954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   19.072956] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   19.072958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   19.072959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   19.072961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   19.072963] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   19.072965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   19.072967] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   19.072969] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   19.072970] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   19.072972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   19.072974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   19.072976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   19.072978] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   19.072980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   19.072981] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   19.072983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   19.072985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   19.072987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   19.072988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   19.072990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   19.072992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   19.072994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   19.072996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   19.072997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   19.072999] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   19.073001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   19.073003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   19.073005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   19.073065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   19.073067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   19.073070] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   19.073073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   19.073075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045DE0C | umac branchlink2
[   19.073077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   19.073079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   19.073080] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[   19.073082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | umac data2
[   19.073084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | umac data3
[   19.073086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000040 | umac major
[   19.073088] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x97BBEE0A | umac minor
[   19.073090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00011236 | frame pointer
[   19.073092] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F38 | stack pointer
[   19.073094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   19.073096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   19.073135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   19.073137] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   19.073186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000071E9 | IML/ROM data1
[   19.073247] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   19.073295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   19.073301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   19.073354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003E0001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   19.073396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   19.073402] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   19.073446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   19.073452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   19.073498] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   19.073505] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   19.073546] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   19.073557] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   19.073598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   19.073609] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   19.073651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   19.073655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   20.221405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   20.234105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   20.234393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[   21.256815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7196, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   21.256864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0x80480c70
[   21.257072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   21.257080] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   21.504450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
[   21.504455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   21.504459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   21.504461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   21.504463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   21.504465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   21.504467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   21.504469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data1
[   21.504471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data2
[   21.504472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   21.504474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   21.504476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   21.504478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   21.504480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   21.504481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   21.504483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   21.504485] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   21.504487] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   21.504489] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   21.504490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | board version
[   21.504492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   21.504494] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   21.504496] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   21.504497] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   21.504499] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   21.504501] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   21.504503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   21.504504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   21.504506] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   21.504508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   21.504510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   21.504512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   21.504513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   21.504515] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   21.504517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   21.504934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   21.504936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   21.504939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   21.504942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   21.504944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045DE0C | umac branchlink2
[   21.504946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   21.504948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   21.504950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[   21.504951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | umac data2
[   21.504954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | umac data3
[   21.504956] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000040 | umac major
[   21.504958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x97BBEE0A | umac minor
[   21.504960] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000111C6 | frame pointer
[   21.504962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F38 | stack pointer
[   21.504964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   21.504965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   21.505166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   21.505167] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   21.505368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00007196 | IML/ROM data1
[   21.505461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   21.505511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   21.505517] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   21.505571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003E0001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   21.505621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   21.505671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   21.505723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   21.505775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   21.505825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   21.505875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   21.505927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   21.505980] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00401410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   21.506030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   21.506082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   21.506131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   21.506135] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   22.680926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   22.694031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Comment: You're using a rather old release (2020-April release) with *outdated* media (an unsupported kernel if using Desktop) with *revoked* keys ([20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) media was created to revokation of keys, though these should update once you apply all security fixes).. Your Fedora wasn't that old in comparison, so why such an old & non-updated version of Ubuntu?  You also didn't say if 20.04 Desktop or 20.04 Server; but I'd start by applying security fixes, rebooting & trying again (*with non-revoked keys which can disable some hardware*)

Comment: If this is the XPS 13 Developer Edition series which Dell installs Ubuntu Desktop on, you should get 22.04 LTS media and do a clean install yourself.  Dell's 20.04 image is *ancient*, *outdated*, and is likely to cause problems.  Unfortunately, they know it but won't change it.

Comment: Please also [edit] in the output of `apt-cache policy linux-firmware`

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Good to know. And, thanks Dell. Just got the XPS back from a long repair hassle and they installed that "ancient" image.

Comment: That linux-firmware doesn't have so-a0-gf-a0-64. You want your dmesg to look like https://launchpadlibrarian.net/671567852/CurrentDmesg.txt . Fedora 39 was released in 2023, so plug in an equally new USB like 23.10, or go with the more stable 22.04 USB Thomas suggested

Comment: Yeah. I decided to install the Fedora 39 i had on hand. Thanks for all comments.